Dapper.Contrib com bug em Case Sensitive (PostgreSQL)
Possuo uma tabela users no meu banco de dados em Postgres com o nome da propriedade id em minusculo. O problema é: Ao usar os métodos do Dapper Contrib, em um método ele espera uma coluna em minusculo e outro método ele espera o nome da coluna exatamente igual ao nome da propriedade. No caso de Update por exemplo, se eu colocar as propriedades com primeira letra em maiúsculo como é o padrão, ele vai esperar que a coluna esteja em primeira letra maiuscula também. ENTRETANTO, se eu vou ao banco de dados e mudo o nome das colunas para primeira letra maiúscula, ao usar um insert, ele vai esperar uma coluna com nome em minúsculo. Alguém já passou por isso?
public class User
{   

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public string Bio { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public string Slug { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{   
    private const string connectionString = @"conexão";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadUsers();
    }

    public static void ReadUsers()
    {   
        
        var user = new User()
        {   Id = 2,
            Name = "banana",
            Bio = "Relações Internacionais",
            Email = "banana@gmail.com",
            PasswordHash = "061180",
            Image = "url",
            Slug = "ba-nana"
        };
        
        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Update(user);
        }
    }

}

SQL é case-insensitive. De onde você tirou que Dapper.Contrib considera o casing pra algo?

@JéfBueno em posgres colunas double-quoted são case-sensitive, ou melhor, o nome é "preservado", pode ser o caso do OP, mas não tenho como confirmar, não uso essa extensão e nem Dapper.

Após um tempo descobri que essa extensão mesmo sendo oficial, aparentemente não possui suporte para mapeamento manual. Acabei optando por Dapper.FluentMap.Dommel que possui os mesmos métodos porém podendo realizar um mapeamento. Obrigado a todos.

@JéfBueno, como eu disse, apenas relatei minha experiência. O Dapper.Contrib permite que você execute métodos abstraindo as queries. Só que ao fazer o mapeamento, ele peca em alguns métodos ao procurar pelo nome da coluna que seja IDÊNTICO ao nome da propriedade do objeto que ele usa pra mapear. Isso faz com que ele acabe fazendo um mapeamento errado. Mas posso ter me equivocado com relação ao título, perdão.
